# How to convert one record per change to continuous data?

Tags: python, pandas, join

My data looks like this:
print(df)

```
DateTime,      Status
'2021-09-01',  0
'2021-09-05',  1
'2021-09-07',  0
```

And I need it to look like this:
print(df_desired)

```
DateTime,      Status
'2021-09-01',  0
'2021-09-02',  0
'2021-09-03',  0
'2021-09-04',  0
'2021-09-05',  1
'2021-09-06',  1
'2021-09-07',  0
```

Right now I accomplish this using pandas like this:

```
new_index = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq='D'))
df = new_index.join(df).ffill()
```

Missing values before the first record in any column are imputed using the inverse of the first record in that column because it's binary and only shows change-points this is guaranteed to be correct.

To my understanding my desired dataframe contained "continuous" data, but I'm not sure what to call the data structure in my source data.

**The problem:**
When I do this to a dataframe that has a frequency of one record per second and I want to load a year's worth of data my memory overflows (92GB required, ~60GB available). I'm not sure if there is a standard procedure instead of my solution that I don't know the name of and cannot find using google or that I'm using the join method wrong, but this seems horribly inefficient, the resulting dataframe is only a few 100 megabytes after this operation. Any feedback on this would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) working with `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df = df.set_index('DateTime').asfreq('d', method='ffill').reset_index()
print (df)
    DateTime  Status
0 2021-09-01       0
1 2021-09-02       0
2 2021-09-03       0
3 2021-09-04       0
4 2021-09-05       1
5 2021-09-06       1
6 2021-09-07       0
```

Comment: I tried this, and while it is more elegant than what i wrote down, it does the exact same thing and using my full dataset it overflows my memory. I can't figure out why, a year's worth of data in second intervals is not even close to 60GB of data.

Comment: I upvoted this because it is the most pythonic way to write down this procedure. I figured out how to prevent memory overflow, although I'm still not sure why it grows so large in the first place. 

First, make sure you use the least memory intensive datatype possible. In my case binary.

Second do this operation one column at a time and stitch the resulting columns together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pipeline:

```
(df.set_index('DateTime')
   .reindex(pd.date_range(df['DateTime'].min(), df['DateTime'].max()))
   .rename_axis('DateTime')
   .ffill(downcast='infer')
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
    DateTime  Status
0 2021-09-01       0
1 2021-09-02       0
2 2021-09-03       0
3 2021-09-04       0
4 2021-09-05       1
5 2021-09-06       1
6 2021-09-07       0
```

input:

```
    DateTime  Status
0 2021-09-01       0
1 2021-09-05       1
2 2021-09-07       0
```

Comment: This still produces the memory overflow problem I talked about in my post. Thank you for taking the time to reply though!